# Tabla de Java WEB a XLS

Tags: excel, java-ee, oracle-12c, jqgrid, xls

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación **Java Web** que además usa una Base de datos **Oracle**, tengo una tabla de registros que obviamente tiene identificadores(ID) y esta tabla de BD puede visualizarse en mi aplicacion Web con ayuda de **JQGrid** esta tabla se exporta en formato XLS con ayuda de una dependencia conocida como **Apache POI**.

La problemática es que al exportar esta tabla a formato **XLS** todos los campos aparentemente se encuentran en orden pero los ID no coinciden debido a que por decirlo de alguna forma se redondean.

Estos son algunos ID de ejemplo que se muestran en la aplicacion web

[image: ID de tabla en la aplicacion WEB]

Y así es como se ve en el archivo XML

[image: ID en documento excel]

¿Qué es lo que puede estar pasando?¿Alguien me puede ayudar en esto? Porque de algun modo se esta redondeando pero no se por que razón.

Comment: ¿La exportación es a Excel (**XLS**) o a **XML**? Donde dices que es así como se ve el archivo... ¿te refieres a Excel en lugar de XML?

Comment: Y otra cosa... eso no es en realidad un redondeo... Abre el excel y vete a Formato de Celda > Número >Selecciona "Número" (no general) con 0 decimales. Y da ancho suficiente a la columna